# Overwrite header of fasta file with a column value, by matching the file name with part of the column value

Tags: pandas, biopython, fasta

**Dataset:**

Submitter | Filename  | Virus

Lyn       | 012345.fasta | abc/USA/abc-**01234567**/1234

Lyn | 012345.fasta | abc/USA/abc- **04567898**/1234

Lyn | 012345.fasta | abc/USAabc- **78935421**/1234

**Files within a directory called 012345:**

**04567898**-abc-a124-pol.fasta

**78935421**-abc-a124-pol.fasta

**01234567**-abc-a124-pol.fasta

Inside of a file:

&**01234567**-abc-a124-pol

ACTGATGATGAGATAGA
ATAGATAGATAGATAG

AGATAGATAGATA

Note: there is the same 8 digit number within Column C, a fasta file name, and the fasta file header.

What I want to do is take the entire string from Column C, and overwrite the current fasta file header. The output would look like this:

**Fasta file name:**

**01234567**-abc-a124-pol.fasta

**Inside of a file:**

&abc/USA/abc-**01234567**/1234

ACTGATGATGAGATAGA
ATAGATAGATAGATAG

AGATAGATAGATA

**Here is a class I am trying to write to do that. I am struggling to get it to work. Please let me know if there is a simpler way.**

```
def parse(file_name):   
    with zipfile.ZipFile(file_name, "r") as zf:
        for name in zf.namelist():
            if ".fasta" in str(name) and '.ipynb' not in str(name):
                with io.TextIOWrapper(zf.open(name)) as file:
                    e = "".join([">{} \n{}".format(str(title.split(None, 1)[0]), identifiers)
                        for title, identifiers in SimpleFastaParser(file)])
                with open("test_dict.fasta", "a+") as f0:
                    f0.write('{}\n'.format(e))
    return file_name       

def names(file_name):
    with zipfile.ZipFile(file_name, "r") as zf:
        e1 = []
        for name in zf.namelist():
            if ".fasta" in str(name) and '.ipynb' not in str(name):
                with io.TextIOWrapper(zf.open(name)) as file:
                    e1 += [title.split(None, 1)[0]
                        for title, identifiers in SimpleFastaParser(file)]
        print(e1)
        return 

def pandas(file_name):
    with zipfile.ZipFile(file_name, "r") as zf:
        e4 = []
        for name in zf.namelist():
            if ".fasta" in str(name) and '.ipynb' not in str(name):
                with io.TextIOWrapper(zf.open(name)) as file:
                    e4 += [{title.split(None, 1)[0]:[identifiers, len("".join(identifiers))]
                        for title, identifiers in SimpleFastaParser(file)}]

                          
                dataset = pd.DataFrame({'Name': ["".join(i.keys()) for i in e4], 
                                        'Length':[list(i.values())[0][1] for i in e4],
                                        'Sequence':[list(i.values())[0][0] for i in e4]})
                   
            
        return dataset
```

Comment: with open(04567898-abc-a124-pol.fasta, 'w') as file:
      for line in file:
           for val in df['fastas']
                 str.replace('&[regex statement here]', val)

Comment: This might be a better way to go? ^